# Animated website scaling/zooming

Tags: javascript, css, html, animation, zooming

Please have a look at [www.mediawiki.org](http://www.mediawiki.org) using Chrome and try increasing/decreasing the page zoom (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd>).

Can anyone give any pointers on how to implement such animated zoom handling? I've noticed it doesn't work in all browsers.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as i know this zooming is a browser property and nothing to do with a particular site. Try any website and this effect will be there. Also in my knowledge this works in all browsers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check css `transition` property

here's some code from MediaWIKI website that made it possible:

```
div#mw-panel div.portal div.body,div#mw-panel div.portal h5 {
    transition:padding-left 250ms;
    -moz-transition:padding-left 250ms;
    -webkit-transition:padding-left 250ms;
    -o-transition:padding-left 250ms;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As anu said, it's handled by the browser, but you make it possible on a site by using percentages and/or ems for things like widths on fonts and margins.

***EDIT***
I didn't look at it in Chrome (even though you said we should), and therefore missed the animations (doh!). Apologies.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure but I think you can achieve the same by creating the website in em or % format and just animate the parent container width and font property... all the child element will automatically animate...
For example... you have font-size of 1em on body element all the child element also have the font-size related to the body container font-size in em format. when you increase or decrease the font-size of body element the child elements will also increase and decrease its font-size and when you animate the body font-size the child element will also animate their font-sizes... 
(This is my Idea may be this helps)...